# PIG script execution through java and grunt

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Somehow if I use grunt shell to execute a pig script, it works fine but if I try java mode, it shows "Failed to create DataStorage" error somehow.

- Grunt mode command is "pig -x mapreduce test1.pig"
- Java mode command is "java -cp $PIGDIR/pig-0.9.2.jar:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR test1.pig"

I am wondering what's wrong with my Java command syntax (or any configuration issue?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your're trying to run a pig script directly from java, which probably wont work. You'll need to embed your script in a complied java class and run that if you don't want to use grunt. This link should explain what to do:

[Embedding Pig In Java Programs](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/EmbeddedPig)

Also, see [this](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/RunPig) for more info on run modes.